# How to get element which don't have a class name and a id using selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

HTML:

```
<a title="ITC" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="TPComView(&quot;2020-2021&quot;,&quot;39&quot;);">ITC</a>
```

I tried using cssSelector and xpath but it shows error like:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To locate the element you can use the `title`, `onclick` or/and `innerText` attributes and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `link_text`:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element_by_link_text("ITC")
  ```
- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[title='ITC'][onclick^='TPComView']")
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@title='ITC' and text()='ITC']")
  ```

Ideally, to locate the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "ITC"))).click()
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[title='ITC'][onclick^='TPComView']")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@title='ITC' and text()='ITC']")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294) in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Comment: I tried your method and it is giving me          selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Answer (score 0):

You can use the find_element_by_xpath function.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="'+url+'"]')
```